# React PropTypes in Meteor doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, meteor

I tried different meteor/react tutorials and I always have the same problem.

I don't know why PropTypes don't display warnings in console if something is wrong. For example:

If I remove title `<TitleBar title="Test title"/>` The code still works normal without warnings even if it's required.

If I change string in object, bool or array `title: PropTypes.string.isRequired` everything still works normal without warnings.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class TitleBar extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TitleBar.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

I also tried official Meteor/React tutorial and I got the same problem.
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

Is PropTypes just for testing purpose?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it works perfectly fine. I get a warning if I provide a non-string.

Comment: @Chris Did you try it on fresh project of meteor?  I made a new meteor project and install this: meteor npm install --save react react-dom
Do you have any ideas what else could be wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell which version of react you are using

Comment: @mitchken I'm using react: 15.6.1, react-dom: 15.6.1, react-router-dom: 4.1.1 and I work on Windows 8.1

Comment: I format my computer and start from the beginning and I got the same problem again. Something must be wrong with the meteor.

Answer (score 3):

install the new package from npm

```
  npm install --save prop-types
```

and import this 
in your code

```
  import React from 'react';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  export default class TitleBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
          return (
             <div>
             <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>

            </div>
                 );
      }
    }

    TitleBar.propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired

      };
```